# Alexa saying "minute" (the time) wrong as minute(very small)

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ssml

Alexa is saying minute wrong, how can I make her say minute as in 60 seconds when replying to my Skill ?

At the moment she says "as of 5 minutes ago" 5 very small objects haha

This is my skill

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "jarvis",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "NSStatus",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "How am I doing"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "UploaderBattery",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "How is my uploader battery"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "PumpBattery",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "How is my pump battery"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "LastLoop",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "When was my last loop"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "MetricNow",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "metric",
                            "type": "LIST_OF_METRICS"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "pwd",
                            "type": "AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "What is my {metric}",
                        "What my {metric} is",
                        "What is {pwd} {metric}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "InsulinRemaining",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "pwd",
                            "type": "AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "How much insulin do I have left",
                        "How much insulin do I have remaining",
                        "How much insulin does {pwd} have left",
                        "How much insulin does {pwd} have remaining"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                    "samples": []
                }
            ],
            "types": [
                {
                    "name": "LIST_OF_METRICS",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "bg"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "blood glucose"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "number"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "iob"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "insulin on board"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "current basal"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "basal"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "cob"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "carbs on board"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "carbohydrates on board"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "loop forecast"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "ar2 forecast"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "forecast"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "raw bg"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "raw blood glucose"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this can't be launched until this is resolved as it just sounds ridiculous hahah

I tried to do some googling and searching on here but its really hard when 2 words are spelt the same to distinguish between minute and minute - see !

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Use [SSML](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html) speech tag for the response texts.

```
<speak>
<say-as interpret-as="time" > 5' </say-as>
</speak>
```

will be pronounced as 5 minutes.

```
<speak>
<say-as interpret-as="time" > 5'10" </say-as>
</speak>
```

will be pronounced as 5 minutes and ten seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The `say-as` tag of SSML will help you to interpret your response in the desired way. You can use `interpret-as="time"` to make Alexa interpret it as time.

```
<speak>
   <say-as interpret-as="time" > 5'10" </say-as> ago.
</speak>
```

Beware that **if you want just "minute"** and not seconds, **use it like 5'0"**. If you only include 5' it will read as *"five apostrophe"*.

```
<say-as interpret-as="time" > 5'0" </say-as> ago.
```

In the same way **for seconds alone use it like 0'10"**. This will read as *"ten seconds"*.

```
<say-as interpret-as="time" > 0'10" </say-as>
```

More on `say-as` tag [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#say-as).

---

### phoneme

If you have some complex pronunciations or the same text has different pronunciations, then use `phoneme` tag to provide its exact phonetic pronunciation.

For example, The *"minute"* (time) and *"minute"* (size) can be pounced differently by giving its exact phonetic pronunciation symbols.

```
<speak>
   <phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="/mʌɪˈnjuːt/">minute</phoneme>particles. 
   One <phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="/ˈmɪnɪt/">minute</phoneme>.
</speak>
```

This will be spoken as
*"minute particles"* and *"One minute ago"*.

More on `phoneme` tag [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#phoneme).